# How to change the position of "base_link" frame?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For navigation, the base_link should be placed at the rotational center of the robot.

My robot is a rectangular shaped robot, whose rotation center is at the front.

How do I change the location of "base_link" from its physical center to its front?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256022/how-to-change-the-position-of-%22base_link%22-frame?/) by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot frame is usually published by your robot driver which integrates wheel encoder values (or in addition with a gyro/imu) in order to broadcast the relative transformation between `odom` and `base_link`. The location of `base_link`w.r.t. the robot body is driver specific here.

Options:

- You could change the driver code, but you would need to compile from source and update the package manually in the future.
- If the driver has the option to change the base_link name, rename `base_link` and add a [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) to your robot launch file in order to create a new `base_link`at the rotational center.
- Create a new link, e.g. `nav_link` at the rotational center with a [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) in your robot launch file. Configure the navigation stack accordingly (the base frame can be set in the global and local costmap parameters). I haven't tried this option yet. Ideally, planners should adhere to the base frame specification in all internal transformations.

Some drivers are only publishing joint states and utilize a [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) to provide the corresponding robot frames from a robot model description, usually a [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) file. Sometimes [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) is utilized to generate URDF files.
In that case, you can adjust the robot model in one of the following ways:

- Move the current `base_link` frame to the rotational center and adjust all inherited transformations (children frames) as well.
- Choose a different name for the current `base_link` frame and add a new `base_link`at the rotational center (e.g. as a child frame from the old one).
- Create a new link, e.g. `nav_link` at the rotational center. Refer to option 3. above for further comments.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on 2017-03-02**:
Thank You for this great explanation.
I have full access to the driver code. What exactly I need to change in the driver code? the transform between `odom` and `base_link`??

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2017-03-07**:
yes, you can add an offset to that transformation in order to shift base_link. But just for the record: it is not the best-practice solution as mentioned above ;-)